# Focus+Context via Brushing for scatter plot in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

How can I make dots responsive to the chart changes via brushing? I've tried to use tranfsorm attribute but it doesn't work good. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AECqY/3/). Coffescript is below

```
# draw dots
dots = focus.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(bubbleData)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", (d) -> 2*Math.abs(d.surprise))
    .attr("cx", xMap)
    .attr("cy", yMap)
    .style("fill", (d) -> color(d.surprise))

brushed = ->
  xScale.domain (if brush.empty() then xScale2.domain() else brush.extent())
  focus.select("._x._axis").call xAxis
  focus.select(".line1").attr("d", line1(data))
  focus.select(".line2").attr("d", line2(data))
  focus.selectAll(".dot").attr "transform", (d, i) ->
    "translate(" + xScale(d.date) + "," + yLeftScale(d.price) + ")"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with the lines, you need to redraw the circles on brush:

```
focus.selectAll(".dot")
  .attr("cx", xMap)
  .attr("cy", yMap)
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AECqY/4/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick solution.